# AWStats and Extra Section with GeoIP country data

Tags: web-analytics, geoip, awstats

I'm new to AWStats, so if this question is unclear, please ask for the needed information.

I'm using AWStats v6.9, with the GeoIP plug-in running successfully.  I would like to write an Extra Section that reports unique page hits for one specific page in my domain sorted by country.  So the table would look something like:

```
Country Code Access for www.mydomain.com/mypage.html:
Country   UniqueHits
USA       10
JPN       5
ES        2
```

and so on.  I can get the unique hits for my one page, but reading the AWStats documentation and .conf file I need a little help figuring out how to include the country data.  Thanks in advance for your thoughtful reply, Stack-Overflow genius!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Jean-Luc at SourceForge page for AWStats:

> Hi,
>
> This is not possible. You cannot use
>   the country list in an extra section.
>
> Jean-Luc, InternetOfficer AWStats
>   Support